# How Mysql trigger for new values?

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a table with language code. i need a trigger, when i adding new line in the table must be generated the new rows with others language codes. for example:

original table

```
|| *id* || *const* || *text* || *i18n_language_codes_id* ||
|| 1 || NAV_HOME || Home || 1 ||
|| 2 || NAV_HOME || Homme || 2 ||
|| 3 || NAV_HOME || Hom || 3 ||
```

when i adding the new line with id 4:

```
|| *id* || *const* || *text* || *i18n_language_codes_id* ||
    || 1 || NAV_HOME || Home || 1 ||
    || 2 || NAV_HOME || Homme || 2 ||
    || 3 || NAV_HOME || Hom || 3 ||
    || 4 || NAV_ABOUT || About || 1 ||
```

need these new results with id 5.6(same const and text, only changes language codes combinations):

```
|| *id* || *const* || *text* || *i18n_language_codes_id* ||
    || 1 || NAV_HOME || Home || 1 ||
    || 2 || NAV_HOME || Homme || 2 ||
    || 3 || NAV_HOME || Hom || 3 ||
    || 4 || NAV_ABOUT || About || 1 ||
    || 5 || NAV_ABOUT || About || 2 ||
    || 6 || NAV_ABOUT || About || 3 ||
```

how can i do this?
sorry for my bad english, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be be able to do that with a trigger in MySQL but most importantly you don't have to.

Assuming that language codes are coming from another table, let's say `language_codes` you can prepopulate the rows for all language codes at once with one SQL statement

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (const, text, i18n_language_codes_id)
SELECT 'NEW_CONST', 'New Text', i18n_language_codes_id
  FROM language_codes
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fc91/1)** demo